# Is it possible to use the randint() function in numpy without the prefix np?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am not using

```
import numpy as np
```

Using this -

```
From numpy import*
```

How do I use the np random included functions without the np prefix?

Comment: `random.randint()` but never import with `from package import *` because it makes it very unclear what package you are using for certain functions.

Comment: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint' - This is showing up.

Comment: That is part of the problem I am talking about above in my comment. At some point did you do `from random import random` . . . again never import with `*` just do `import numpy as np; np.random.randint()` Also, restart the kernel.

Comment: So there is actually no way to call np's built-in functions without the prefix?

Comment: there is . . . `from numpy import *; random.randint()`

Comment: Yes, it does work. Thanks. I was actually wondering how will the random library and np's inbuilt functions be handled by the interpreter. Not a good practice after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` import works ok:

```
In [1]: from numpy import *

In [2]: random
Out[2]: <module 'numpy.random' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py'>

In [3]: random.randint(10)
Out[3]: 6
```

That said, we strongly recommend that you use

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint...
```

Nearly all SO `numpy` answers use that.